# Ubuntu "eats" space on disk

Tags: disk, disk-usage

I have a strange problem with Ubuntu. The space od my disk is eaten by system, probably. I have a disk separated into 3 areas - boot, exchange and free space for data. The sizes are 60GB, 16GB and 180GB. I feel the disk do not work fluency. The problem is connected with boot part - Normally I should have there 40GB of free space and after boot computer every day I have it, butafter few hours this space is smaller (currenlty 26GB of free space) and I do not know why. I dont install any programs, I just surf internet or use intellij - thats all. And free space is smaller. 
This is my output from `df -h`:

[image]

A you can see `/dev/sda1` is the problem - it take more space all the time.

I have tried to do all thigs I know: clean, autoclean, clear logs and also used BleachBit - nothing helped. But after restart I have againa 40GB of free space which is reducing by the time I'm using system. What could be a source of this problem and how to repair it?

**EDIT:**

After installed `ncdu`, I got this info:

```
 8,9 GiB [##########] /var                                                                  
    4,2 GiB [####      ] /usr
  793,3 MiB [          ] /lib
  723,3 MiB [          ] /opt
  137,7 MiB [          ] /boot
   14,7 MiB [          ] /etc
   12,2 MiB [          ] /bin
   11,0 MiB [          ] /sbin
   88,0 KiB [          ] /tmp
   56,0 KiB [          ] /snap
   48,0 KiB [          ] /root
e  16,0 KiB [          ] /lost+found
```

Looks like `var` folder is too big. Go deeper:

```
5,8 GiB [##########] /gdm3                                                                 
    2,3 GiB [####      ] /snapd
  323,2 MiB [          ] /mongodb
  191,8 MiB [          ] /apt
   73,5 MiB [          ] /dpkg
```

Gdm3 is very big and its logs:

```
/var/lib/gdm3/.local/share/xorg 
                         /..                                                                   
    3,6 GiB [##########]  Xorg.0.log
    2,2 GiB [#####     ]  Xorg.0.log.old
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Is the `/tmp` folder on your main partition? That one contains temporary data and is cleared during every boot, if it isn't mounted as RAM disk anyway.

Comment: Yes, it is. How can I fix it? I ran `sudo rm -r *` in this folder, but it did not help.

Comment: You're not supposed to delete the stuff inside while your applications which might use it are running. But is it really a problem? It gets automatically cleaned on every boot anyway. If you're interested, you can check what folders of it are the largest with `du -h -d1 /tmp | sort -h | tail` to maybe find out which applications use most of it.

Comment: Yes it is a problem, because after few hours I get info on screen that I have 1 Gb of space left and needs to reboot

Comment: I see. So what does investigating the contents of /tmp reveal? Any hints to what application might use that much? Several GB of /tmp files are definitely not normal and whatever is leaking so much data in there seems to be broken.

Comment: Probably locally installed couchbase, but I need to make sure

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/301745). Instead, copy the text, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) to make it look nice.

Comment: Install and run `ncdu`. It is a command-line disk usage analyzer. I use it regularly. Use `ncdu -x /` and it will show you the usage of your `/` filesystem and we should be able to pin point what exactly uses up space. Likely some sort of caching or extensive logging is being done.

Comment: I would suggest running the second `ncdu` command in my previous comment **after** you have disk space eaten up, so that you can see where did it go. If you run that on a cleaned-up drive, obviously that won't tell you anything useful

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy - I have installed `ncdu` as you suggested and edited main post. It looks like logs from `GDM3` eats my disk. Could you look at it and tell how to fix it?

Comment: Looks like I found how to fix it. I edited `custom.conf` file in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and comment line with `#WaylandEnable=false`

Comment: It looks like your Xorg is filling up your logs, probably with an error. I've had this before. You can set the logs to limit their size as a short term fix; but you'll want to fix the problem causing the logs to fill up. This issue is a symptom of your Xorg problem.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like I found how to fix it. I edited `custom.conf` file in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and comment line with #WaylandEnable=false. Now I do not have `xor` logs anymore and nothing "eat" space on disk.

Comment: Congrats on  finding the workaround !  `Xorg`  is the graphics or GUI  and minimal logs for it are fine, but the amount of logging described in your question is definitely a concern.  Along with this, I would recommend submitting a bug report on launchpad https://launchpad.net/gdm  and saving some of the repeated errors that occur in the log. Chances are the developers should know about this